# Dell XPS 8500 how to disable the msata ssd from being used as a caching device

Tags: ssd, dell-xps, msata

Is there a way to disable the msata ssd to be used as a caching device?

I want to install a regular SSD drive in sata 3 port and I don't want it to be cached by the msata. Otherwise it will make it slower?

I tried with the intel SRT software. But it's seems to be read only. You can not make any changes to it. is it hard wired to cache?

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply change a setting in the Bios from Intel rapid start to ACHI. Make sure you backup everything before you do that as it may screw the whole system configuration